# Generate CA signed ECDSA certificate

Tags: certificate-authority

I need a CA signed ECDSA certificate for testing purposes.
I am able to generate an ECDSA certificate and key but I have never signed one.
I use OpenSSL in a Windows environment to generate certificates.
Is there any way to generate a free CA signed ECDSA certificate?
If not, can someone provide the steps (openssl) to sign my generated certificates?

Comment: [This might be what you're looking?](https://superuser.com/questions/1103401/generate-an-ecdsa-key-and-csr-with-openssl) SuperUser is probably the better StackExchange for this type of question.

Comment: Thanks @RoraΖ . But, the link mentions about generating csr (which we need to forward to a Certificate Authority). But, are there CAs that do free singning for testing purpose? If not, I am looking for steps to generate root CA key and certificate and sign on my own, especially steps to perform the signing.

Comment: [How to sign a certificate request with openssl](https://blogg.bekk.no/how-to-sign-a-certificate-request-with-openssl-e046c933d3ae). If there's something about the process you don't understand then I would edit this question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's Encrypt supports [ECDSA keys](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#using-ecdsa-keys):

> As of version 1.10, Certbot supports two types of private key algorithms: `rsa` and `ecdsa`. The type of key used by Certbot can be controlled through the `--key-type` option. You can also use the `--elliptic-curve` option to control the curve used in ECDSA certificates.

Comment: Thanks @Esa. I have never uses Let's Encrypt. Did not see any easy user guides as well. If you know any, please share. For the time being, I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: The link on this answer goes to the Certbot User Guide... Then there is also https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/